# How can I bind a Symfony config tree to an object

Tags: symfony

How would I go about binding a Symfony config tree to a class rather than returning an array?

Using `Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Processor` returns an array.

In my case I want the config to be bound to a class so I can use methods to combine parts of the data.

Here is a simple example of my use case. I want the config bound to a class so I can use a method to join table.name and table.version together (my actual use case is more complex, but this is a simple example)

**config.yml**

```
  db:
    table:
      name: some_table
      version: v2
```

**ConfigurationInterface**

```
class DBConfiguration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('db');

        $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('table')
                    ->children()
                        ->scalarNode('name')->isRequired()->end()
                        ->scalarNode('version')->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
        ;

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

**Class I want to bind the config to**

```
class DB
{

    public $table;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->table = new Table();
    }

}


class Table
{

    public $name;
    public $version;

    /**
     * @return string
     * Calculate the full table name.
     */
    public function getTableName()
    {
        return $this->name.'-'.$this->version;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Symfony Config component doesn't support that.

However, in a Symfony project, this is usually done at the [container compile phase](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html). In your bundle's `Extension` class, you will have access to the configuration tree of your bundle in array form.

You can then take this array and assign it to a service defined in the service container that will create your config object.

This is exactly how `DoctrineBundle`'s configuration class is built:

1. [Abstract services (for the configuration and the factory) are defined in `dbal.xml`](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/v1.2.0/Resources/config/dbal.xml#L46-L52)
2. [When loading `DoctrineBundle`'s extension, an instance of the abstract config service is created for each defined connection.](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/v1.2.0/DependencyInjection/DoctrineExtension.php#L103)
3. [An instance of the abstract factory service is created for each defined connection.](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/v1.2.0/DependencyInjection/DoctrineExtension.php#L103)
4. [The options array is then passed to the abstract factory service along with the configuration](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/v1.2.0/DependencyInjection/DoctrineExtension.php#L159-L167)
5. [When creating an instance, the factory then does the necessary transformations](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/v1.2.0/ConnectionFactory.php#L51-L71).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Symfony has no native support for this, however, you could implement it yourself. You could use subset of [Symfony Serializer Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) in charge of deserialization, but I think it would be an overkill. Especially since I don't see any `PublicPropertyDenormalizer`, only `GetSetMethodNormalizer` (which is denormalizer too). Therefor you would have to either make your config objects have `get/set` methods or roll `PublicPropertyDenormalizer` on your own. Possible but it really seems like an overkill and doesn't look like helping much:

#### Symfony Serializer Component

```
$array = [
    'field1' => 'F1',
    'subobject' => [
        'subfield1' => 'SF1',
    ],
];

class MyConfigObject implements Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DenormalizableInterface
{
    private $field1;

    private $subobject;

    public function getField1()
    {
        return $this->field1;
    }

    public function setField1($field1)
    {
        $this->field1 = $field1;
    }

    public function getSubobject()
    {
        return $this->subobject;
    }

    public function setSubobject(SubObject $subobject)
    {
        $this->subobject = $subobject;
    }

    public function denormalize(\Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DenormalizerInterface $denormalizer, $data, $format = null, array $context = array())
    {
        $obj = new static();
        $obj->setField1($data['field1']);
        $obj->setSubobject($denormalizer->denormalize($data['subobject'], 'SubObject'));

        return $obj;
    }
}

class SubObject
{
    private $subfield1;

    public function getSubfield1()
    {
        return $this->subfield1;
    }

    public function setSubfield1($subfield1)
    {
        $this->subfield1 = $subfield1;
    }
}

$normalizer = new \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer();

$obj = (new MyConfigObject())->denormalize($normalizer, $array);
```

#### Native PHP Way

Imo this is a lot easier than above as Symfony Serializer wasn't really ment for that.

```
$array = [
    'field1' => 'F1',
    'subobject' => [
        'subfield1' => 'SF1',
    ],
];

trait Denormalizable
{
    public function fromArray($array)
    {
        foreach ($array as $property => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                if ($this->$property instanceof ArrayDenormalizableInterface) {
                    $this->$property->fromArray($value);    
                } else {
                    $this->$property = $value;
                }
            } else {
                $this->$property = $value;
            }
        }
    }
}

interface ArrayDenormalizableInterface
{
    public function fromArray($array);
}

class MyConfigObject implements ArrayDenormalizableInterface
{
    use Denormalizable;

    public $field1;

    public $subobject;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->subobject = new SubObject();
    }
}

class SubObject implements ArrayDenormalizableInterface
{
    use Denormalizable;

    public $subfield1;
}

$myConf = new MyConfigObject();
$myConf->fromArray($array);
```

Whatever way you choose, you can now just take array returned from symfony processor and turn it into a config object you need.